# change text attribute of an option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to change text attribute of an option using its value as a variable.

My trying doesn't work, any help, pls.

Expecting result is:

```
<option value = 2>earth</option>
```

```js
var x = 2
var str = 'earth';

$('button').on('click', function(){
$('#sela:option[value = ' + x + ']').attr('text', str); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='sela'>
<option value = 1>lorem</option>
<option value = 2>ipsum</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$('#sela>option[value = ' + x + ']')` to select the direct `option` child of `#sela`.

And use `text()` to update the option text.

```js
var x = 2
var str = 'earth';

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#sela>option[value = ' + x + ']').text(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='sela'>
  <option value=1>lorem</option>
  <option value=2>ipsum</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```